# Angular Material custom theming

Tags: angular-material, angular-material2

The mat-core() mixin is not getting recognized by my scss file. It shows error as "Undeclared mixin".

```
@import '~@angular/material/_theming';
@include mat-core();
```

Comment: which version of material ?

Comment: @angular/material@2.0.0-beta.10-6b5100b @Faisal

Comment: are you importing another pre-built theme as well ?

Comment: No i tried using it, but removed it altogether !

Comment: use `@angular/material@2.0.0-beta.10`

Comment: how to change it now ? But aren't both beta 10 ?

Comment: just change the version in `package.json`. The one you are using `@angular/material@2.0.0-beta.10-6b5100b` is a build repository, may have errors.

Comment: now it shows in package.json as "@angular/material": "^2.0.0-beta.10",

Comment: Nope still the problem is occuring

Comment: Update your angular/cli version and give proper path value for importing angular theme in first line. It solved my problem @Faisal

Answer (score 4, accepted):

after couple of hrs spending i finally figured it out instead of this

@import '~@angular/material/theming';

***USE THIS***

**@import '../node_modules/@angular/material/theming';**

(*Issue is with the path*) :)

Answer (score 0):

Update your angular/cli version and give proper path value for importing angular theme in first line. It solved the problem